# Deploying Jersey web service application in Jboss as 7.1.1 shows webservices in package ws is not supported

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jersey, jboss7.x

I have an issue on deploying my war file ,everything expect the web services are working fine The error log is given below

```
16:14:08,866 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:com.fut.ws

16:14:08,920 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/fut-wager]] (MSC service thread 1-1) StandardWrapper.Throwable:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.ScannerException: The URI scheme vfs of the URI vfs:/content/fut-wager.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/fut/ws/ is not supported. Package scanning deployment is not supported for such URIs.
Try using a different deployment mechanism such as explicitly declaring root resource and provider classes using an extension of javax.ws.rs.core.Application at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:225) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1] at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:139) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1] at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1] at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1] at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1] at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]

16:14:08,974 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/fut-wager]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Servlet /fut-wager threw load() exception: com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.ScannerException: The URI scheme vfs of the URI vfs:/content/fut-wager.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/fut/ws/ is not supported. Package scanning deployment is not supported for such URIs.
Try using a different deployment mechanism such as explicitly declaring root resource and provider classes using an extension of javax.ws.rs.core.Application
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:225) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:139) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556) [jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]

16:14:09,038 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /fut-wager
16:14:09,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "fut-wager.war"
16:15:00,034 INFO  [com.fut.scheduler.MatchScheduler] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-9) -- Match expiring scheduler execution started --
16:15:00,037 INFO  [com.fut.ws.user.handler.MatchHandlerImpl] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-9) --Inside match expiring service--
16:15:00,039 INFO  [com.fut.dao.user.MatchDao] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-9) --Inside match expiring dao--
16:15:00,313 INFO  [com.fut.scheduler.MatchScheduler] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-9) -- Match expiring scheduler execution completed --
```

Comment: The exception gives you an error message of what the problem is, and what you can try to fix it.. _"The URI scheme vfs of the URI vfs:/content/fut-wager.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/fut/ws/ is not supported. Package scanning deployment is not supported for such URIs. Try using a different deployment mechanism such as explicitly declaring root resource and provider classes using an extension of javax.ws.rs.core.Application"_

Comment: If you're unsure of how to do that, see [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#d4e188)

Comment: I have tried certain things but it doesn't changed

Comment: Did you try exactly what the error message suggests?

Comment: I had changed my web.xml by commenting "<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>org.foo</param-value>
</init-param>" now the project deployed successfully, but the call to web services are not working

Comment: I gave you a link. Please look at it and try to implement the Application sublcass as described in the link. Then register that Application class in your web.xml. The link shows exactly how to do it

Comment: ok fine.. Thank you @peeskillet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got same error and solved using link provided by peeskillet. Here is example :

**Web Service Application**

```
package org.webservice.application;    
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.webservice.rs.HelloWorldService;

public class RSApplication extends Application
{
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(HelloWorldService.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

**Resource**

```
package org.webservice.rs;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService
{
    @GET
    public Response getMsg()
    {
        String output = "I M Jersey";
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>J2EEDemo</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>org.webservice.application.RSApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml** entry for dependency

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Hit url : `http://<HOST>:<PORT>/<CONTEXT>/rest/hello`

Answer (score 3):

I also got the same problem. below works for me try it.

Problem: `com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.ScannerException: The URI scheme vfs of the URI vfs`
`

Solution: Need to change web.xml file

I have created 
 - package : `com.rest.spring`
 - class   : `PaymentService`

and I have provided those values inside `<init-Parm>` in the `web.xml` file.  See below:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            **<param-name>
               com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
            </param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.spring</param-value>**
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

After deploying, I got above error.  So the only thing we need to change that is `<init param>` see below:

```
            **<param-name>
                javax.ws.rs.core.Application
            </param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.spring</param-value>**
```

enjoy...